# Is CUDA in installed correctly on my Ubuntu 10.04? Some samples don't run.

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cuda, gpu

I am trying to install CUDA on a server running Ubuntu 10.04.

I followed the NVDIA instructions and installed the "CUDA toolkit for Ubuntu Linux 10.04", "GPU Conputing SDK code samples",and "Developer Drivers for Linux (260.19.26) (64 bit)", my system is 64 bit. This installation seems successful. everything downloaded from http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cuda_3_2_downloads.html#Linux

According to the messages of the installation packages, I added /usr/local/cuda/bin to PATH, /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Then, I tried to run the sample programs. The strange things is, some of them can be run, and some of them don't even through they can be made with no problem.

For example,
- `convolutionSeparable` will just stop there without any message, I can kill it by ctrl + c.

- `matrixMul` outputs a line

  `Device 0: "Quadro 5000" with Compute 2.0 capability`

  and stop there, again can be killed by Ctrl+C
- `clock` works, outputs

  `PASSED`
  `time = 12574`
  `Press ENTER to exit...`
- `simpleMultiCopy` outputs `PASSED`
- `MonteCarlo` outputs `PASSED`
- `simpleZeroCopy` outputs `PASSED`
- `bandwidthTest` stops there with blinking cursor for ever.

What is wrong with this?! How can I check if my CUDA installation is successful ? What is wrong with those programs don't run? They don't even have a error message.

Comment: Do you have any other devices aside from your Quadro 5000?

Answer (score 4):

I would start by upgrading the driver to `260.19.36`, which [can be found here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-260.19.36-driver.html).  Then I would suggest running `nvidia-smi -a` to see if the driver is happy.  Then I second the suggestion to run `deviceQuery` to see if the CUDA Toolkit 3.2 is working.

If deviceQuery output appears nominal, then I would start adding printf's to see where things go awry in matrixMul.

Answer (score 2):

What does deviceQuery say? Also check the output of dmesg right after you run that program to see if you can figure out whats up.

Another tip, if you still are having issues, is try running:

```
strace ./deviceQuery 2> out.txt
```

Then check out.txt to see if you can find any clues why this error is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem but solved by updating kernel and drivers.

install newer kernel on 10.04

```
linux-image-generic-pae-lts-backport-natty
linux-headers-generic-pae-lts-backport-natty
```

download the latest nvidia driver
from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

install the latest CUDA (at moment 4.0) from
http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-40

```
CUDA Toolkit for Ubuntu Linux 10.10     32-bit
CUDA Tools SDK  32-bit
GPU Computing SDK code samples
```

then I passed all SDK example tests.

ThinkPad w520 Quadro 1000 on Ubuntu 10.04